# where to find default view code in user relationships module in drupal 7?

Tags: views, users

I have installed user relationship module. Which gives me default views to display the list of friends, received requests and sent requests. I want to show a message to the user about the number of requests he/she has received as we see in facebook. But I am not getting the view's machine name, display name to take a count of requests received as I am not getting which is the view for requests received. Where Can I find it?

Comment: Can I fetch view's machine name and display using url?

Comment: It is not an answer to your question, but look at those modules: [Link Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_badges), [Menu Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under User Relationship module there will be a folder called `user_relationship_views` inside that you can find the default view `user_relationship_views.views-default.inc` file